# Zero-length URL Segments

Tags: python-2.7, flask, werkzeug

Using the latest versions of  Flask and Flask-RESTful, I have some very basic routes defined as such:

```
def build_uri_rules(uri_map):
    for cls, uri in uri_map.iteritems():
        api.add_resource(cls, uri)


uris = {
    SampleController: '/samples/<string:hash_or_id>',
    SampleFamilyController: '/samples/<string:hash_or_id>/family',
}

build_uri_rules(uris)
```

This works for uris requested 'properly', but what if the /samples/ endpoint is hit without a parameter, or the sample*family endpoint is hit with an empty sample id? Currently, this results in a 404 error. This works well enough, but I believe the proper thing here would be to throw a 400 error, as they found a proper URL but their data is improperly structured. Is there a way that I can force this behavior?

As a side note: 
Looking through the Werkzeug docs, I see that werkzeug.routing allows a minimum length for certain url parameters, but I also see that it's got a minimum of 1. Admittedly, I've not look for why this is the case, but would this be the right tree to bark up? or should I rather simply create a global 404 handler that checks for the length of the parameter and raise the *proper* error from there?

Thanks!

**EDITED**: For code correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that hitting `/samples/` or `/samples/family` (or even `/samples//family`) *should* result in a 404 as there is nothing at that endpoint.

If, however, you want to do otherwise, the simplest way to handle it would be create a 404 handler for *just* `/samples/` and `/samples/family` that returns a note with more information about what the consumers of your API are most likely doing wrong.

```
uris = {
    Explanitory400Controller: '/samples/',
    SampleController: '/samples/<string:hash_or_id>',
    Explanitory400Controller: '/samples/family',
    SampleFamilyController: '/samples/<string:hash_or_id>/family',
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what we're doing, but I'm using some trickery to parse the uri definition inside build_uri_rules. (Basically, I'm looping over each string and removing the variable portion of it, and binding that to a 400 Controller, which simply aborts with the error message.) We're also using a bit of reflection to allow the user to hit / and get a list of all of the endpoints, which should mitigate confusion in our case. Thanks for this answer, as it sheds some light for others on 400 vs 404, and explains both.